# Accepted way to reactive (bump?) a question

Tags: discussion

I found a question on stackoverflow which is exactly the question I would like to post. There is one answer, not up-voted, not marked as correct (and not what I would accept). The answer is six month old, so I think there is a good chance that if I would re-post the question, I would get additional answers.

But since the question exists already, I don't want to re-post the same. Rather I would like to re-activate the question such that it looks very similar to a new questions.

What is the accepted way to do this?

Comment: you can offer a bounty!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Quite a popular question so it even got its own faq entry.